# return filename from G_CALLBACK in GTK

Tags: c, char, gtk, return-value

Hey guys so I would like to return value of filename from function (or pointer) but Im to sure how to do it. My filename stores path to file name /home/username/file. So here is my main

```
gchar *filename = NULL;

button = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "button1" ) );
g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (show_dialog), &filename);
```

And show dialog look like this

```
static void
show_dialog ( GtkWidget *button,
          gint       response_id,
          gpointer   user_data )
/* Init filechoosedialog, builder etc */
{

gchar *filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (filechoosedialog));

}
```

Do I need to change static void show_dialog to gchar show_dialog and at end do I need   to do return filename; and what else do I need to declare because Im getting compile error

```
 warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

So I would like to add code like this to my main and to get value of filename

```
if filename != NULL
g_print ("Selected filename: %s\n", filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a misunderstanding of event driven programming. You don't do things like this in main(), you do it in the event handler. In your example you would call `g_print()` from `show_dialog()`.

If you want to do something more complex you'll need to know some application state: that's what the g_signal_connect() userdata pointer is for. As an example, if you want to set the filename as the text of a label, you would set a pointer to the label as the user data pointer and can then set the label text in the event handler.

More generically, the userdata pointer can be anything: e.g. a data structure that you can use to store the filename string. Typical usage is an application data struct that is allocated in main: The struct contains all "application global" variables (like filename) and a pointer to the struct is given to all GTK+ callbacks so all functions can access and modify the struct contents.

If the problem was using the userdata pointer, here's an example using just a pointer to the filename as userdata:

```
g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (button_clicked_cb), &filename);

static void
button_clicked_cb (GtkWidget *button,
                   gint       response_id,
                   gpointer   user_data)
{
    char **filename_ptr = (char**)user_data;
    *filename_ptr = g_strdup ("newly allocated string that the filename pointer in main() stack will now point to");
}
```

Comment: But I cant do it diferently, on button1 clicked program show filechooserdialog then you cshoose file and click ok, originaly I have g_prinf in show_dialog as example but now I want to have it avalible in main or in another function and I realy do not understand how that is misunderstanding, there is no another way

Comment: If you explained what you want to do, maybe we could help. The point of the "label as userdata pointer" example was that you can indeed make the string available elsewhere... it's just that "returning to main()" makes very little sense in event driven programming like GTK+: you probably realized that main() doesn't directly call show_dialog(), so it makes sense that it can't directly get the return value either.

Comment: Ok I understand, I said return to main() because what if I need (or want) to pass filename() as 4th argument to another G_CALLBACK() function, I planned it like that its that simple, so what I need to do is to set up some memory memory management, but first I need to learn how and what else do I need, do you have any idea ?

Comment: You can just pass the address of `char *filename` as 4th arg, no problem with that (just remember in the callback handler that the argument is a char**). But the application data struct is probably the right direction for any non trivial app: this string won't be the last piece of data you need to store.